# Python: binary file to gz file and then to jpg extension and finally return again to the original binary file

Tags: python, file, binary, smtp, imap

I want to do the following in Python:

1. Take a binary (executable) file
2. Turn it into a zip file with gzip (gz extension)
3. Then put the jpg extension

Later again the desire to recover the original (without the gz extension or jpg).

The idea is to send binary files through GMail SMTP to recover and then get them over IMAP and process them in ehtir original form (1).

Comment: If you downvote, please comment to explain why!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The python `gzip` and `shutil` libraries can do what you need.

To gzip the executable.

```
import gzip, shutil

src = open('executable', 'rb')
dest = gzip.open('executable.gz.jpg', 'wb')

shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)

src.close()
dest.close()
```

And then to get the original back.

```
import gzip. shutil

src = gzip.open('executable.gz.jpg', 'rb')
dest = gzip.open('executable', 'wb')

shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest)

src.close()
dest.close()
```

That being said, gmail's MIME filters look at content, not extension, so it may still block the new file.

Comment: and how do then recover the original executable?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and then tell you something

Comment: is there any way to send the executable without the gmail MIME block?

Comment: The only way I can think of is to encode the binary data in base64 format, which will make gmail's MIME filters validate it as textual data (which is allowed).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`gzip`](http://docs.python.org/library/gzip.html) to compress the files and [`os.rename`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.rename#os.rename) to change file names. In your case you could just use `gzip` and save it with a `.jpg` extension in the first place.

```
import gzip

# write compressed file
with gzip.open('my_file.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(content)

# read it again
with gzip.open('my_file.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    content = f.read()
```

Comment: This has got, so I would like to see the code, I can not recover the original file.

Comment: Thanks but not quite understand the structure of the code ... will be that you could explain?

Comment: You use the [`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) statement to open the file to be used for compression using `gzip.open`. You then write the contents of your file to be compressed (where `content` represents the file you are trying to compress, which must be `read()` from) with `f.write(content)`. To decompress your file you use `gzip.open` again to open the compressed file as `f`, which is decompressed as you `read()` it.